# Gerar cabeçalho MySQL dinâmico

Tags: html, mysql

Tenho abaixo um problema que não estou conseguindo solucionar.

Como fazer para que o cabeçalho tenha o nome do funcionário e abaixo dele a receita que foi gerada de acordo com a data?

E como ficaria uma tabela em HTML com esses?

A primeira imagem é uma query simples que montei só pra demonstrar a estrutura da minha tabela.

A segunda é como que eu quero que fique.

@EDIT
Eu consigo fazer algo semelhante, porém agora não sei como vou montar minha tabela HTML. Os IDS e nomes serão dinâmicos, onde vou montar de acordo com cada funcionário que tenho no meu banco. Coloquei estático só como exemplo.

```
SELECT P.dt_venda as venda, 
SUM(CASE WHEN P.id_consultor = 4 THEN IR.receita_gerada_receita END) as funcionario4,
SUM(CASE WHEN P.id_consultor = 3 THEN IR.receita_gerada_receita END) as funcionario3,
SUM(CASE WHEN P.id_consultor = 2 THEN IR.receita_gerada_receita END) as funcionario2
FROM item_receitas as IR, funcionarios as F, pedidos as P
WHERE P.id_consultor = F.id
AND IR.id_pedido = P.id
GROUP BY venda, F.nome
```

[image: Tabela SQL]

Comment: dá uma pesquisada sobre pivot

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, vou dar uma estudada sobre, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Certo @rLinhares, coloquei o código, obrigado.

Comment: Você tem que criar uma tabela HTML como qualquer outra, usando as tags <table>, <th>, <tr>, <td>. Coloque seu código PHP do que você fez até agora, com relação a consulta e exibição de dados, ajudaria bastante.

Comment: Meu codigo php seria somente essa query, agora eu preciso da lógica de como montar as linhas e as colucas da tabela.
O problema é: O nome dos campos é dinâmico, como eu controlaria isso pra montar minha tabela ?